# How to create blob using the response of url in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have tried creating blob using the following code:

```
var res = JSON.parse(response); 
var file = new Blob([res.data], {type: res.headers['content-type']});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
console.log(fileURL);
```

The blob is not created as per the data. eg. for an image it shows empty small image.

Comment: What is `res.data`?

Comment: res object is received from server , res.data contains the actual file content;

Comment: What is  "the actual file content"?

Comment: if it's a html file, res.data contains the source code.

Comment: Is `res.headers['content-type']` `application/json`? Is expected result a `Blob URL` of `html` file?

Comment: yes which would render same as original html file and content type is text/html

Comment: Is `html` within `JSON` properly escaped? `javascript` at Question should return expected result. Cannot reproduce issue  http://plnkr.co/edit/I5coA5cOalABHbNSbtqP?p=preview

Comment: Actually I am saving file in mongo using gridfs, I just want to fetch the contents of the file  and display the actual file using blob url . If I access the file using the url , it works fine , but I want to fetch the content of the file using ajax and then display the content of any ( be it any html , image, etc. ) using blob url

Comment: Not clear what you mean. `javascript` at Question renders expected result as demonstrated at linked plnkr

Comment: Suppose I have a url of a pdf file and I just want to create a blob for this

Comment: You would need to get the `.pdf`, then create a `Blob URL`, as demonstrated at plnkr using `javascript` at original Question. Does `javascript` at plnkr not return expected result?

Comment: It returns the expected result, Thanks :)

Comment: the data field used here is a simple html tag , but in my case it is not always the url but the actual content, like it shows weird symbols when image is fetched

Comment: How is data fetched?

Comment: It is fetched through post url with certain security params passed in the body , it is not a public url

Comment: Use `fetch()`, `Resposne.blob()`

Comment: Okay . Thanks a lot ! :)